# PHP PDO is saving string from javascript object (ajax) as empty field

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, pdo

This is interesting and by that I mean incredibly frustrating.

I am passing this data to my php file via an ajax call: `{"html":"<div>I'm a div!!</div>"}`

I want to preface this next statement by saying that I do understand the reasons for not saving json to a database, but it does have a use here.

When I save this data to the database field, the field is empty. Now see this:

```
$in1 = file_get_contents('php://input'); //from ajax
var_dump($in1);
$in2 = '{"html":"<div>I\'m a div!!</div>"}';
var_dump($in2);
```

value of my ajax call:

```
string(33) "{"html":"<div>I'm a div!!</div>"}"
string(33) "{"html":"<div>I'm a div!!</div>"}"
```

Perfectly the same! Yet, `$in2` will save to the database just fine!! While `$in1` yields an empty field!!

To be certain, consider this:

```
if ($in1 === $in2) { echo "They're equal!"; }
```

Go figure...they're exactly equal, yet one will save correctly and the other won't. Amazing.

Further: `mysqli` does not have this issue, so that narrows it down to being a PDO issue.

```
$query = "UPDATE plugin_instances SET config=(?) WHERE id=2";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $in1);
$stmt->execute(); //correct value in the db!!
```

I have now removed everything and this is the whole php file.

[Non-working output](http://pastebin.com/xujBRSPG)
[Working output](http://pastebin.com/MPwt8YcT)

The only difference between these two is the result of `$stmt->rowCount()`.
The sample that correctly updates the field says `int(0)` and the one that empties it says `int(1)`.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=disarray', 'root', 'temp');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
var_dump($db);

$params = [':foo'=>'{"html":"<div>I\'m a div!!</div>"}'];
var_dump($params);
$params = [':foo'=>file_get_contents('php://input')];
var_dump($params);

$query = "UPDATE plugin_instances SET config=:foo WHERE id=2";
var_dump($query);

try {
  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  var_dump($stmt);
  $stmt->execute($params);
  var_dump($stmt);
  var_dump($stmt->rowCount());
}
  catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I really wouldn't let execution continue after catching a `PDOException` at that point. Better to just let that bad boy go uncaught and catch it further up. Also, changing `$params=false` to `$params=array()` means that you won't need to check it, just run `$stmt->execute($params)`

Comment: Can you run a debugger and set a breakpoint or put in some manual debugging in the `exec` method before preparing the statement, eg `var_dump($query, $params, $fetch); exit;`

Comment: All equal in every way. I'm going to try to remember how to do `mysqli` just to eliminate another factor. Or heck, non prepared.

Comment: What do you mean "*all equal in every way"*? We're trying to debug a problem with your live data, not compare it to a working test set. What do you see from the debugging (add it to your answer)? Have you removed the `try` and `catch` block? If not, do that.

Comment: Also, make sure your environment has error reporting enabled for development. In your `php.ini` file, make sure you have `display_errors=On` and `error_reporting=E_ALL`. If you make changes, don't forget to restart your web / app server

Comment: One more thing; how are you verifying that the update statement doesn't work?

Comment: Aren't you storing JSON strings in db, are you?

Comment: By the way, your db wrapper is almost as smart as it can be. Is it of your own production or you have acquired it somewhere?

Comment: Ouch. @YourCommonSense, sounds like you need to post a question about how to treat someone with dignity. I do the best I can. @Phil I mean that I dumped all the values (even used php to compare them) and they were exactly alike (`===`). The statement IS working. It returns that 1 row was updated using `$stmt->rowCount()`. I updated code to use that. It just stores nothing for `$in1`. I promise I checked the params and everything. I even unwrapped all of it and tried (that's the first thing I did before posting this).

Comment: I've changed the name a few times, but why not. I'll report back soon.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. It wouldn't work with your test data if that were the case.

Comment: The downvotes are ridiculous. This seems like a very ideal question... I've put a ton of work into and it's certainly interesting.

Comment: this is a question on some silly typo actually, nothing else. and sure offtopic because of this.

Comment: @YourCommonSense what typo? Can you see any?

Comment: Could you please (and I mean this literally), remove any reference to `$in2` and any hard-coded test data, add `var_dump($query, $params, $fetch); exit;` as the first line of your `exec` method, make a request and **add the output from the script to your question**?

Comment: No. I am not a computer but human. the code intended to be *run* not read. I can tell a typo just from the statement of question. PDO that doesn't save something in database is a nonsense. So, only a silly typo remains as a reason.

Comment: @YourCommonSense That's great, considering I have posted that mysqli handles it perfectly well and php compares both as equal. Typo? Really?

Comment: @m59 In all honesty, he's probably right. This will most likely be something extremely trivial where you'll slap yourself on the head and wonder why you spent so much time on it. Now, please see my [comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627814/php-pdo-is-saving-string-from-javascript-object-ajax-as-empty-field#comment27425215_18627814)

Comment: Yes. Some sort of typo or similar mistake. You did a lot of the proper things investigation the problem, but still you need more. More clear test cases, more proofcodes. If I were you, I'd write this mysqli stuff with proof code in the same file with PDO stuff, run it, and post whole code along with output. But to proceed you need to understand that it is surely not PDO's fault but yours. Too many thousands people using PDO and none have such a problem.

Comment: Again, how are you verifying that an error has actually occurred? From memory, MySQL will return a row count of zero for an UPDATE statement that doesn't make any changes so you cannot rely on `PDOStatement::rowCount`. You need to be **in** the DB (preferably via console) running SELECT queries to verify the results.

Comment: I updated my question again. Just before the last code block are links to the working/non-working output. The only difference anywhere is the rowCount.That doesn't make any sense. They should both be returning `1`. They do both update the field, but the one returning 0 is the one doing it correctly!

Comment: Every test I run, I change the value back and forth. There is no "error". I'm telling you, they both "work" in that they are updating the field back and forth, but one empties the field and no error is given. As I said, the zero is the one updating it correctly, so that really adds to the confusion. And yes, I am checking in phpmyadmin to verify the values. I have been from the beginning.

Comment: :'(  I figured it out. @YourCommonSense you were right, it isn't "this" code. There was another (and unecessary) ajax call firing in my app that was coming through 2nd and erasing the value. Putting the value in directly made them both run the same update. I was doing all the debugging in php and didn't even think it could be a js issue. That's what being obsessive does :(  I'll delete this in a moment, unless it would serve anyone any good to post my find.

Comment: @Phil, so sorry for wasting your time :( I did learn a lot of in this process and really appreciate your bearing with me.

Comment: Please don't delete it. Better write an answer, explaining all the trouble. I'll be happy to upvote it

Comment: Should I update the title?

Comment: Nope, it is considered wrong way on this site. Just accept your own answer when it lets you to.

Comment: Ok. I read your comments about SO. You make a lot of good points. I could have just solved this whole issue with a jQuery function, right? :) I hope I didn't come across like one of those guys. I recently left my job and have been coding for most of my days since. I am determined to make this my career and I don't accept shabby work from myself. I also don't accept my snoodiness. That being, I apologize. I don't know if you meant harm or not, but I don't have any ill-will about it. I appreciate your time. Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what my certain words you are talking about. Speaking of your database wrapper class, I meant it, no sarcasm. Good class, save for some details. Speaking of harsh words from my profile - yes, I meant harm but I don't see how it's connected to you.

Comment: @YourCommonSense lol. Then my apology was very necessary. I thought you meant that my wrapper was as awful as it could be. I did make several improvements since I posted it. I was quite stressed last night and dealing with some other good ole' SO bullies. (downvoting good answers)

Comment: I was after that `$fetch` variable practically. I've never seen anyone who come across such a simple yet useful feature. Most people trying to distinguish queries by the first word, which is flawed by design. However, personally I would have two different methods for selecting all the rows and running a query that returns no data. As well as having two additional methods for returning a single row and scalar value. it come extremely handy when you have to use the query result

Comment: The only objection I have for your class is `echo $e->getMessage();`  line which is a big no-no. You have to get rid of `try..catch` at all - PHP will handle your error mighty better way. Yet it will make `try..catch` available wherever you will **really** need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massive *sigh*. The issue is with my javascript, not php. I was testing this out in my api, which several things make calls to throughout my somewhat large app. There was an additional ajax call being made that I was unaware of (it was left in the code by error) and it wasn't sending any data, so my test script in the api was running with no data and thus emptying the database field right after I wrote to it. Of course, entering the data directly into the script worked out great because both calls were doing the same thing.

It is unfortunate that when I stripped down my php code, I used the same filename/location. 
More unfortunate is that the success of the `mysqli` threw me even further off, solidifying in my mind that the issue was with PDO. It turns out that it was just changing which ajax call was responded to last.

And thus, I have hopefully learned not to have so much tunnel-vision when going through the debugging process.